# How do I pass multiple values with one radio button?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am creating a web app and I want that a single selection (trough radio button) from the user pass values to two different columns on my table (one string and one int).

I am hoping to solve this with some razor radio button syntax elegant trick, but any solution is welcome.

currently my code is just a simple razor html helper:

```
            <td>
                <td>@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.MedicationPeriod, "Morning" )    </td>
                <td>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.MedicationPeriod, "Morning")</td>
            </td>
            <td>
                <td>@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.MedicationPeriod, "Morning and Night")</td>
                <td>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.MedicationPeriod, "Morning and Night")</td>
            </td>
```

What I would expect would be something like this (that I know doesn't work):

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.MedicationPeriod, "Morning", model => model.TimesPerDay, 1)
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.MedicationPeriod, "Morning and Night", model => model.TimesPerDay, 2)
```

Comment: Can we see your code?

Comment: And... should we start from scratch? Please post some code.

Comment: code added. I thought it was more of a theoretical question, sorry

Answer (score -1):

I've made this two extensions methods. You can use the second with a list of `SelectListItem`.

```
    <Extension()> _
    Public Function RadioButtonList(ByVal helper As HtmlHelper, ByVal name As String, ByVal Items As IEnumerable(Of String)) As String
        Dim selectList = New SelectList(Items)
        Return helper.RadioButtonList(name, selectList)
    End Function

    <Extension()> _
    Public Function RadioButtonList(ByVal helper As HtmlHelper, ByVal Name As String, ByVal Items As IEnumerable(Of SelectListItem)) As String
        Dim sb As New StringBuilder
        sb.Append("<ul class=""radiobuttonlist"">")
        For Each item In Items
            sb.AppendFormat("<li><input id=""{0}_{1}"" name=""{0}"" type=""radio"" value=""{1}"" {2} /><label for=""{0}_{1}"" id=""{0}_{1}_Label"">{3}</label></li>", Name, item.Value, If(item.Selected, "selected", ""), item.Text)
        Next
        sb.Append("</ul>")
        Return sb.ToString()
    End Function
```

Nothing fancy, but works.